# how to use aws route53 list-resource-record-sets cli

Tags: escaping, aws-cli, amazon-route53, jmespath

I am trying to use aws route53 cli command to list out resource record sets in a zoneId with a query

```sh
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
  --hosted-zone-id $zoneId \
  --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'abcd.example.com.']"
```

But I am getting this error

```
Bad value for --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name: Bad jmespath expression: Unclosed " delimiter: "ResourceRecordSets[?Name
```

I tried several approaches

```sh
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
  --hosted-zone-id $zoneId \
  --query \"ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'abcd.jazz.t-mobile.com.']\"
```

```sh
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
  --hosted-zone-id $zoneId \
  --query \"ResourceRecordSets[?Name == \'abcd.jazz.t-mobile.com.\']\"
```

But every time I am getting the same error, anything I am doing wrong?
Also I am not running this in terminal but in a jenkins script so I am doing it the following way

```sh
sh(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
  --hosted-zone-id $zoneId \
  --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'abcd.example.com.']")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using back ticks to wrap the value you're searching for

```sh
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
  --hosted-zone-id $zoneId \
  --query 'ResourceRecordSets[?Name==`abcd.example.com.`]'
```

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter):

> When specifying a literal value such as "us-west-2" above in a JMESPath query expression, you must surround the value in backticks (` `) for it to be read properly.

Comment: Does this work when you have over 100 records in HostedZone?

Comment: @Pawel It does as I have 146 records at the moment.

Comment: surprisingly, it does work. Even though you'd think client-side filtering (`--query`) wouldn't work with paged results, it somehow does. I confirmed with a zone with 1400 records. Pro-tip: don't use `--max-items` as that seems to mess things up (you'll get zero results).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Try without extra " in the command.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $zoneid --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'domain.com.']"
```

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html)

Comment: Tried this, but gives the same error. Also as I mentioned, I have to use " to wrap the command since I am executing this using sh script in jenkins